# sqlite3 open error (macOS, swift5, Xcode 11.3.1)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, sqlite

I was able to access what was placed in Bundle Resources.

Unable to access the locally stored database.

please tell me.

Thank you.

Source

```
    // Connection OK
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "sqlite3")!
    // Connection NG
    // let path = "/Users/userName/Desktop/test.sqlite3"

    var db: OpaquePointer?

    if sqlite3_open(path, &db) != SQLITE_OK  {
        print("db open error.")
        return
    }
```

Console

```
2020-01-28 17:44:03.392512+0900 TestApp[3920:163470] [logging-persist] cannot open file at line 43353 of [378230ae7f]
2020-01-28 17:44:03.392754+0900 TestApp[3920:163470] [logging-persist] os_unix.c:43353: (0) open(/Users/userName/Desktop/test.sqlite3) - Undefined error: 0
db open error.
```

Comment: Is your app [sandboxed](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxQuickStart/AppSandboxQuickStart.html) perhaps?

Comment: Thank you.
Had been sandboxed.This part is not well understood.
what should I do?
Setting "User Selected File" of "File Access Type" to "Read / Write" failed.